# What is diffrent between Time dimension And Standart dimension in Mondrian?

Tags: olap, cube, mondrian, rolap

I have fact table with `date_id` column and date table with `year`, `month`, `day` columns. I can create a dimension with one dimension type. What influences the choice of the type? I dont see the diffence between this types in results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to label a dimension as a time Dimension if you want to use time arithmetic functions such as `MTD` or `QTD`: http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php#Time_dimensions